# IDA hexrays decompiler

Tags: ida, decompilation

Sometimes i see such lines. What do they mean, such syntax?

> (*(void (__fastcall **)(int, int))(*(_DWORD *)v2 + 24))(v2, v4);

```
int __fastcall sub_1(int a1, int a2)
{
  int v2; // r4@1
  int v3; // r5@1
  int v4; // r6@1
  int v5; // r0@2
  int v6; // r0@2
  unsigned int v7; // r0@4
  int v8; // r5@8

  v2 = a2;
  v3 = a1;
  sub_2(a2);
  v4 = *(_BYTE *)(sub_3(*(_DWORD *)(v3 + 1684)) + 13);
  (*(void (__fastcall **)(int, int))(*(_DWORD *)v2 + 24))(v2, v4);
  if ( v4 )
  {
    (*(void (__fastcall **)(int, _DWORD))(*(_DWORD *)v2 + 56))(v2, *(_DWORD *)(v3 + 1700));
```

Comment: In what context?

Comment: this what context in

Comment: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/ppt/decompilers_and_beyond_white_paper.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very likely what you're looking at is a virtual method call on a class.

Virtual methods are usually implemented by the use of a pointer to a table of function pointers. The pointer is added at the beginning of the class data and is added transparently by the compiler if a class has a virtual method.

First it casts v2 to a pointer to a DWORD, reads the DWORD (vtable pointer), adds 24 to the vtable base pointer, reads the pointer to the method at offset 24 in the vtable, casts that to a function pointer and calls it.

Since v2 is both used to locate the vtable pointer and passed as the first argument it's likely the this pointer.